# QUnit testing AJAX calls

Tags: ajax, testing, qunit

I am trying to figure out how I would run a QUnit test on an AJAX call, I've searched on the web and also on here however, I'm still a little lost. I have an AJAX call which essentially just goes to the URL of `pageAJAX.php`, in here there is some PHP/MySQL code which just runs an INSERT query, of a page number and a module number, so the function savePgID, expects those 2 parameters.

**script.js:**

```
function savePgID(moduleID, pageID){
    $.ajax({  
        url: "pageAJAX.php",  
        method: "POST",   
        data: {moduleID:moduleID, pageID:pageID},
        dataType: 'json', //ajax to expect JSON data type
      });
  }
```

**unit-tests.html:**

```
Qunit.test("Testing AJAX call", savePgID(moduleID, pageID) {
$.ajax = function() {
    equals(pageAJAX.php);
    options.success("Hello");
}
equal("Hello");
});
```

Completely lost and unsure how to run a QUnit test on an AJAX call. any guidance at all? Obviously I wouldn't actually want to alter or modify the AJAX call by testing it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting up QUnit tests for AJAX calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61682131/setting-up-qunit-tests-for-ajax-calls)