# OnClick -> checking ajax update with QUnit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

First i was trying to test a QUnit in jsfiddle. It works.

http://jsfiddle.net/chLge79y/28/

i read interesting things here. But looks a bit over complicated to me:

[I tried to maka a QUnit async test for checking ajax update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62621033/i-tried-to-maka-a-qunit-async-test-for-checking-ajax-update).

My plan was to wait about a second for the corresponding data to be uploaded via Ajax (*userName*).
Loading the data via Ajax works (userName and other things).
I think it's nice when loading the data and checking it are two separate, **separate functions**. Click on a link or button to load and start the test.

my first prototype was:

```
function testUserName(){ // 1 prototype: always true
    setTimeout(true, 2000); // check again in a second
    // ^--- its not waiting. has no effect
    QUnit.test( "test Leanne Graham. ", function( assert ) {
       assert.equal( userName, "Leanne Graham", "userName should be Leanne Graham" ); 
    }); 
}
```

that to fast. always is loading the last value.

That's my first QUnit tests.

Comment: `setTimeout` is not a blocking method.  It takes a callback as the first argument, and it executes that callback after the duration has passed.  The logic outside of the setTimeout continues to execute procedurally.

Comment: if found something that looks nearly easy to understand for me: $(document) . ajaxStop(function () { testUserName2(); }  here my update: http://jsfiddle.net/chLge79y/42/

Comment: You are using `fetch()` to perform your ajax logic.  That is outside of jQuery.  jQuery has no knowledge of any ajax request that is not made through its methods.

Comment: @Taplar hmm. i seems working here: http://jsfiddle.net/chLge79y/48/ tried many times

Comment: Throw a console log inside the ajaxStop method.  It never executes.

Comment: @Taplar yes youre right. but funny the tests alway work with this method. problably random just becose of good internet conenction http://jsfiddle.net/chLge79y/53/

Comment: "Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery checks whether there are any other outstanding Ajax requests. If none remain, jQuery triggers the ajaxStop event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the.ajaxStop () method are executed at this time." ( https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/ )
hmm i think that sound not so bad

Comment: Again, that only applies to those ajax requests originating from `$.ajax` or one of the wrappers.

Comment: This attempt uses even more JQuery and works for me: `QUnit.config.autostart = false; ... jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users ... $(document).ajaxComplete ... QUnit.start()`  https://gist.github.com/4cc2ca41f9adf41d8257e525cc2e9dd0